# java.lang.ref.Finalizer OutOfMemory After Memory Raise

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory, finalizer

Extracting a heapdump I realized it has a lot of objects waiting finalization, most of them are instances from libraries like jdbc connections and so on.

Knowing that those instances on the queue are basically classes that implements `finalize()`, why would they simply not be finalized?

A few days ago I raised the memory of such instance. Initially it had 1GB with new generation set to 256 MB (`-Xmx1g -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m`). As we added some heavy caching functionalities we raised the memory assigned to that instance to 3 GB (`-Xmx3G -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m`). From that moment we start to see some out of memories. Investigating it a bit I found out a lot of java.lang.ref.Finalizer and objects waiting for finalization.

How could this be related to each other? May it be even related?

Answer (score 3):

> why would they simply not be finalized?

Some components take longer to finalize esp anything which involves IO.  JDBC connections are relatively heavy weight network resources so they take even longer.

I suggest you use a connection pool (most JDBC libraries have them built in)  This way you are not creating/destroying them all the time.

Note: to clarify `1Gb` = 1 gig-bit or 128 MB (Mega-bytes) `256 mb` is 256 milli-bits or about 1/4 of a bit. `-XX:NewSize=512m` is 512 MB not 256 MB. and `-XX:MaxNewSize=512` wouldn't work as it is just 512 bytes, most likely you used `-XX:MaxNewSize=512m`

`3Gb` is 3 giga-bits but assuming you meant 3 GB it is not `-Xmx1G` which is 1 GB or 8 Gb.

Comment: what I'm a bit curious is how this would be related, why does this problem with the `finalize()` popped up only after the memory change, would this be related to the ration I used between new generation and old generation?

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth The application you have which is generating the resources to be finalized is slower when you have less memory.  It could be multi-threaded.  If you give it more memory it can create more resources to be cleaned up but the single threaded finalizer can't keep up so it becomes the bottleneck. In short, when you speed up one bit, you move the performance problem somewhere else, possibly breaking it in the process.

Answer (score 2):

[Object.finalize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--) is called by the garbage collector on final step of the cleanup.  The GC runs periodically (depending on which GC you are using, if 7 and 8 it's probably CMS, or [G1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/g1-intro-jsp-135488.html) if you so configured).  Having a lot of objects in 'waiting finalization' may mean that you have a large heap and enough memory that the GC did not need to run (CMS most likely, as G1 runs micro cleanups a lot more frequently).

Add GC tracing to your JVM startup parameters and monitor how often it runs:  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps  See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

If you are using lots of small objects with a heap >1Gb you may want to consider using the G1 garbage collector as it is better suited for such a task and doesn't have the 'stop the world' behavior of CMS.